# When using Delphi 10.1 Berlin and Indy with TIdCompressorZLib with some sites, it crash with a zlib error -3

Tags: delphi, zlib, indy

I encounter issues with some sites when reading them with Indy (using firemonkey framework) and using TIdCompressorZLib.

For example, the site http://www.sfgate.com/weather/ will crash indy with a zlib error -3, which I am not able to catch anyhow. On a MAC, it will just close the program and shows a runtime error 231.

```
id:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
id.Compressor:=TIdCompressorZLib.Create(nil);
st:=tmemorystream.create;
try
id.get('http://www.sfgate.com/weather/',st); <- crash with zlib error -3
except
...
end;
```

id.response.ContentEncoding shows "deflate", which might not be right, because I get also a crash when trying to decompress the data manually with the DecompressDeflateStream function of the TIdCompressorZLib class.
But when using just DecompressStream, it will work without error.

So my question is, how can I handle this without a crash, but having Indy do the decompressing?

Comment: Delphi's OSX compiler in Berlin seems to have a problem handling raised exceptions, which would account for your app crashing (this is the second time in as many days that I have seen someone report an exception raised by `TIdHTTP` causes an app crash on OSX). In general, Indy's ZLib handling is buggy. In this situation, I would suggest either replacing `TIdCompressorZLib` with a custom `TIdZLibCompressorBase`-derived class that decompresses "the right way", or don't use `TIdHTTP.Compressor` at all, just set `Request.AcceptEncoding` manually and then decompress `st` after `Get()` exits.

Comment: There is already an open ticket for this issue, I have added your example to it so I do not forget it: https://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/21268

Comment: I am still having the same issues with runtime error 231 when too many exceptions are triggered on macOS, even with the latest Delphi 10.3.2
Is there nothing what can be done about that crash and app vanishing?

Comment: Complain to Embarcadero about their compiler's faulty exception handling on OSX.